# Is there a way to improve vertex curves?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm a bit of beginner when it comes to Blender, so thanks for any upcoming patience.

Perhaps I start with the ambition.

Below is a reference to what I'm looking to achieve; round dips with a tight space between them. With an even number of dips that are all equal in shape and size/

[image]

Below you can see what I''ve attempted...

[image]

I've tried the following:

- First: Dragging or extruding vertexes then applying a subsurface - this gives me the width of the dips and gaps but I can't get the dips to curve like the reference. I could sculpt them but not sure how it would be symmetrical all the way round.
- Second and third attempt was just grabbing a few vertexes then moving along Z axis but that doesn't give the small gap I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi :). There's somewhere an almost identical question about modeling a ghost... just can't seem to find it :))

Comment: @JachymMichal how weird, that's exactly what I was looking for, and that's the same reference I'm using. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your project :)